# XCode 7 : Linker error (library not found)

Tags: xcode, ionic-framework, sdk, xcode7, linker-errors

I have an linker error on a project, made with Ionic Framework.

```
ld: library not found for -lVGPlayer
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I found a lot of posts about this kind of error, but all the solutions I tried fail.

**Build Settings** :

- Enable Bitcode: No
- Other Linker Flags: -ObjC -lresolv -lstdc++
- Library Search Paths: *[none]*

**Hierarchy** :

[Hierarchy of my current project.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHBeN.png)

**Build Phases** :

[Build Phases of my current project.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRUFe.png)

You can here see that the files of the SDK I'm trying to use are in a group (VogoSDK), so the references seems linked to this project.
Note that the libVGPlayer.a appears in that group, in my Build Phases, but not in the Frameworks folder of my hierarchy.

I tried to copy the files in the SDK group in a folder at the root of this project, and then set a "Library Search Paths" to this new folder (Library Search Paths: $(PROJECT_DIR)/VogoSDK). I get these errors :

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/TheSleepingCookie/mhb/platforms/ios/VogoSDK/libVGPlayer.a, missing required architecture x86_64
  in file /Users/TheSleepingCookie/mhb/platforms/ios/VogoSDK/libVGPlayer.a (2 slices)
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_VGPlayerLib", referenced from:
    objc-class-ref in Vogo.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

So I have two questions :

- What is the cause of these errors (my settings, the SDK, my hierarchy, XCode 7, ...) ?
- How can I solve that ?

Thanks for any answer. Ask me for any detail :)

I dont know if it works on XCode 6, i'll try it later.

**EDIT** : I tried with XCode 6.4. The VGPlayerLib.h file in the VogoSDK folder was not set as "target" of my project. The error was a little bit different, speaking about Match-O Type.
After a new search, I added a "Headers" section in the Build Phases and add the file in Public section. Nothing changed, but I'm sure my problems are relative to a little hidden setting... simple feeling :p